# What would the best query be for selecting values from two separate database tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to output something based on these database values, there are two tables. users and transactions. users has the following fields:

```
id, username, firstname, lastname, usertype, points
```

The second table, transactions has the following:

```
id, sender_id, receiver_id, points
```

The `sender_ID` is the ID of the person who sent the points, `receiver_id` is the ID of the person receiving, and so on.

How can I query it to output values from both tables in php, so it would display like this:

> John Doe has sent Jane Doe 3 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try it?

In MYSQL

```
SELECT CONCAT(u1.firstname,' ',u1.lastname) as sender,CONCAT(u2.firstname,' ',u2.lastname) as receiver,t.points as points
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id=t.sender_id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id=t.receiver_id
```

In PHP

You retrieve

```
echo $row['sender'].' has sent '.$row['receiver'].$row['points'].' points';
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: @user1654748: you need to debug that. It's probably that you have a query error - try catching the error before using the result resource.

Comment: what did you given in while($row=mysqli_fetch_array(?

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row['sender'].' has sent '.$row['receiver'].$row['points'];

    }

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT CONCAT(u1.firstname,' ',u1.lastname) as sender,CONCAT(u2.firstname,' ',u2.lastname) as receiver,CONCAT(t.points,' points') as points
FROM transaction t
INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id=t.sender_id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id=t.receiver_id");


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row['sender'].' has sent '.$row['receiver'].$row['points'];

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT CONCAT(u1.firstname,' ',u1.lastname) as sender,CONCAT(u2.firstname,' ',u2.lastname) as receiver,t.points as points
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id=t.sender_id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id=t.receiver_id"); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['sender'].' has sent '.$row['receiver'].$row['points'];

Comment: Fantastic, it's working! Haha, is it possible to ORDER BY with this query?

Comment: Yes which field u want to order?

Comment: Is it possible to load one more field into that query? It's 'date'

Answer (score 1):

Just use two joins to the same table:

```
SELECT u1.firstname, u2.firstname, t.points FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN user u1 ON u1.id = t.sender_id
INNER JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = t.receiver_id
WHERE t.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Joins...

```
SELECT `t1`.`username`, `t2`.`username`, `t`.`points` FROM transactions `t`
INNER JOIN `table` `t1` ON `t1`.`id` = `t`.`sender_id`
INNER JOIN `table` `t2` ON `t2`.`id` = `t`.`receiver_id`
WHERE `t`.`id` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can make a `LEFT JOIN` (eg: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm) or you can use this:

```
SELECT a.username, a.firstname, a.lasname, b.points, b.receiver_id
    FROM table1 a, table2 b
    WHERE table1.id = table2.sender_id;
```

Comment: Don't you need to join to `transactions`? Also, you've specified a `LEFT JOIN` but have used an (old-style) inner join.

Comment: Oups I forgot to put: "or you can use this".